# php IF statements inside `array()` function

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, ranking

I am trying to set an array based on query results that are NOT Null.  In turn I hope to somehow create a ranking based on the NON Null results.

SQL Query returns:

```
Comp1    Comp2   Comp3   Comp4   Comp5   Comp6   Comp7   Comp8   Comp9
NULL     NULL    226.97   274    NULL    208     189     NULL    198.99
```

My PHP:

```
$COMP1 = $rankresult['Comp1'];
$COMP2 = $rankresult['Comp2'];
$COMP3 = $rankresult['Comp3'];
$COMP4 = $rankresult['Comp4'];
$COMP5 = $rankresult['Comp5'];
$COMP6 = $rankresult['Comp6'];
$COMP7 = $rankresult['Comp7'];
$COMP8 = $rankresult['Comp8'];
$COMP9 = $rankresult['Comp9'];
```

This does not work as I am trying to only put in variables that are NOT Null:

```
$myarray = 'array(
        if(!empty($COMP1)){ 
        $COMP1,}
        if(!empty($COMP2)){ 
        $COMP2,}
        if(!empty($COMP3)){ 
        $COMP3,}
        if(!empty($COMP4)){ 
        $COMP4,}
        if(!empty($COMP5)){ 
        $COMP5,}
        if(!empty($COMP6)){ 
        $COMP6,}
        if(!empty($COMP7)){ 
        $COMP7,}
        if(!empty($COMP8)){ 
        $COMP8,}
        if(!empty($COMP9)){ 
        $COMP9})';
```

Desired output:

```
$myarray = array(226.97,274,208,189,198.99)
```

Comment: You database design is probably flawed. However, why not just use the original array and remove anything that's null?

Comment: I don't understand.  Shall I post my MySQL Query?

Comment: @ToddN col1, col2, col3 where `col` is the same name is typically an antipattern.  It signifies that data is not properly normalized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array-filter)?

```
$result = array_filter($rankresult);
```

Result:

```
array(
    "comp3"=>226.97,
    "comp4"=>274,
    "comp6"=>208,
    "comp7"=>189,
    "comp9"=>198.99
)
```

Comment: This appears as though it will work for me, I had forgotten about the `array_filter` function.

Comment: @ToddN: +1. While it will work, note that there is a more fundamental problem underlying here. You're welcome to PHP chat channel [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) and we'll explain it to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you though about using a loop?

If you have the size of the result query, you can do something like this:

```
$myarray=new array();
for ($ix=1; $ix<$num_rows; $ix++) {
    if (${COMP.$ix}!=NULL)
        array_push($myarray,${COMP.$ix});
}
```

Updated.

Comment: Or you can use `foreach` over `$rankresult`.  Also `$COMP$ix` is a syntax error.